# How to post to an http api and get the JSON data back, in lift?

Tags: scala, httpclient, lift

I'm new to lift, and now I want to visit an external http api, post some data and get the JSON data back.

The information is:

```
url: http://mytest.com/login
method: post
accept: application/json
params: {
           "username":"username",
           "password":"password"
        }

response: {
              "result":"ok/failed",
              "message":"welcome/failure reason"
          }
```

Since this is a lift project, and you know lift has provided many useful libraries. I wonder if lift has provided some functions to do this?

If not, is it any other good scala libraries I can use? Or do I have to use apache's java http-client library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, Lift does not have any built in functionality for handling requests to external services.

I'd recommend taking a look at [Dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html). It has many great libraries for abstracting the HTTP interaction and is totally Scala based.

Comment: +1 for dispatch. Make sure to use the lift internal JSON parser. It's really cool.

Comment: I found the DSL of dispatch is really hard to understand, and the documentation is poor. Why you recommend it, or do I missing anything?

Comment: I agree that the documentation could be better, but so could Lift. I use it regularly, the futures support of the new version is pretty cool, error handling is easier, and I personally like the DSL. There is native support for things like XML parsing which makes transforming responses really easy. And as @gzm0 mentioned, the previous version had direct support for lift JSON parsing (http://dispatch-classic.databinder.net/Lift+JSON.html) though I am not sure if that made it to the most recent version. If there is something specific you want to accomplish, I am sure we can help you out.